# adding respective values of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add the respective values of array(first values of all the array together, second value of all the arrays together and so on...)

I know this question is asked many times but still i can not find a suitable answer for my self

I am trying but it adds up the all the values in array one and so on

```
        var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];

        //calculate the total of this data set
        var total= dataset.data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
          return previousValue + currentValue;
        });
        //get the current items value
        var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
         console.log(currentValue)

        var percentage =  (((currentValue/total) * 100)).toFixed(2);
        console.log(total)

        return percentage + "%";
      }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample dataset and the expected output?

Comment: Good=[100,200,300] , Opportunity=[50,100,150] , Bad=[20,40,60] now i want to calculate the percentage of Good as follows: 100/100+50+20 * 100  but my code is doing something like this 100/100+200+300 *100

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but we need a **sample input** and **sample output**. Example: input: [1,2,3]. Expected output: [4,5,6]. Current output i'm getting: [1,4,5]. Otherwise it's quite hard to properly help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the wanted percent values.

```js
var dataset = [100, 200, 300],
    total = dataset.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }),
    result = dataset.map(function (value) {
        return (value * 100 / total).toFixed(2) + ' %';
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it does the same thing which my code was doing earlier

Comment: its doing the same thing which my code does it still adds up the whole array rather than adding first value of first array + first value of second array + first value of third array

Comment: i have a problem to decipher your wanted result. please add the given data to the question and the wanted result as wll as the way to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you desire (as someone else pointed out in the comments), but given you said

> I want to add the respective values of array(first values of all the array together, second value of all the arrays together and so on...)

Here's a snippet that'll take an array of `n` arrays of length `m`, and return an array of length `m` where the `i`'th element is the sum of the `i`'th elements of all `n` input arrays.

```js
let arrays = [[10, 20, 30], [1, 2, 3], [100, 200, 300]];

let sums = arrays[0]
    .map((col, i) => arrays.map(row => row[i]))
    .map(a => a.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));

console.log(sums);
```

Comment: can you help with my code with same variables my dataset lies with dataset.data

Comment: sure, please clarify your question first.

Comment: see the array which gets returned is array of length but its like this [NaN, NaN, NaN] it does not have any value

Comment: that doesn't really clarify what you're asking

Comment: see the variable which i declare is var total is returning a int by adding all the values of the  array but what i want is that it add the first value of first array + first value of second array + first value of third array and i dont a new array i only want to have that total value which is the sum of first elements of all the three array i am really sorry for your trouble , i am fairly new to programming

Comment: You seem to be describing what my snippet is doing. Could you clarify what you are asking for that is different from my snippet?

Comment: this snippet returns an array with NaN values , so thats why I am asking you to please tune it according to my code , for that my dataset lies in dataset.data

Comment: this snippet returns `[111, 222, 333]`. What would you like to return instead?